# No sound in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS new install

Tags: 16.04, sound

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04, there was no sound on my 64 bit desktop pc. I followed the following link.

[Installed Lubuntu 16.04 version no audio now](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774458/installed-lubuntu-16-04-version-no-audio-now/775588#775588)

The sound worked. But on restart, it is not working.

Please help

I have followed the Step 3 of [sound troubleshoot page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) and the output can be found in the following link.
http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=09d65a90decc72f32dd97521497ae03894308c6e

Comment: Check in the device manager>additional driver tab....is your audio driver turned on?? If not...mark it use it..and apply

Comment: There are two additional drivers in that tab and it is using both. 1. HDA Driver in DKMS format from Intel. 2. Processor microcode firmwire from Intel.

Comment: Ohk..search for audio hardware installed in your machine and search for it derivers..if it doesn't work in even other os ..it might be hardware issue... hope u get anyone who can help u more

Comment: I don't think it is hardware issue because until now it was working perfectly. It stopped working after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: enter `sudo lspci` and type your password. See if an audio controller or audio device is listed—it should have the sound card's make and model number. sudo lspci -v will show a list with more detailed information.

You may be able to find and install drivers for your card by searching the Internet

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `pavucontrol` on your system by typing this command in your terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

after that you can check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fu0jOFpudB0)

if this not work , try  [these steps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) in ubuntu wiki
i hope it's solve your problem

Comment: I have followed the above but it is still not working. I have updated the question with more information.