# No sound in system at all after installing puredata

Tags: sound, 17.10, alsa

I installed puredata to play around with audio signals. It didn't work at first saying it does not have alsa permissions. After I rebooted the system the puredata seems to be working fine and produces sound, but nothing else in my system have audio anymore. I removed puredata and rebooted again but the problem persists.

Comment: What is the output of `aplay -l` and `amixer` and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped fixed the issue 
[Installed Lubuntu 16.04 version no audio now](https://askubuntu.com/questions/774458/installed-lubuntu-16-04-version-no-audio-now) 
I removed all alsa packages and killed all pulsaudio processes, then rebooted the system