# Ubuntu 17.10 no sound or dummy output

Tags: 17.10

I just re-installed Ubuntu 17.10 and I can't seem to get the sound working. I am on Kernel 4.16 and even dummy output is not visible.

[image: Sound settings screenshot]

Comment: Try the solutions from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/774458/installed-lubuntu-16-04-version-no-audio-now It's a different Ubuntu version but it might work.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. I got `no protocol specified` after I ran `sudo gksu pavucontrol`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the laptop/PC model or even better, the sound card model.